# How do I keep adding up numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I keep adding up numbers in Javascript?
I am able to calculate what the user puts in, and make a total of that. But how to I make a total of what Javascript prints in a div id, as in `totaal1` and `totaal2` in this case?

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Hier vul je de titel van je pagina in.</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var getal1 = ( document.javascript.normaal1.value - 0 );
        var getal2 = ( document.javascript.alu1.value - 0 );
        var getal3 = ( document.javascript.rvs1.value - 0 );

        var getal4 = ( document.javascript.normaal2.value - 0 );
        var getal5 = ( document.javascript.alu2.value - 0 );
        var getal6 = ( document.javascript.rvs2.value - 0 );

        var getal7 = 'totaal1' + 'totaal2';

        document.getElementById('totaal1').innerHTML = (getal1*0.40) + (getal2*0.50) + (getal3*0.60);

        document.getElementById('totaal2').innerHTML = (getal4*0.40) + (getal5*0.50) + (getal6*0.60);

        document.getElementById('totaal3').innerHTML = getal7;
    }
    </script>

    <form method='post' name='javascript'>

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Ring</th>
        <th>Normaal Per stuk 0,40 </th>
        <th>Aluminium Per stuk 0,50 </th>
        <th>RVS Per stuk 0,60 </th>
        <th>Totaal</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1mm</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='normaal1' onchange='test()' ></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='alu1' onchange='test()' ></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='rvs1' onchange='test()' ></td>
        <td><div id="totaal1">&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2mm</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='normaal2' onchange='test()' ></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='alu2' onchange='test()' ></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='rvs2' onchange='test()' ></td>
        <td><div id="totaal2">&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Totaal</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><div id="totaal3">&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
    </form>

    </table>   
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: document.javascript is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @Diodeus - Sure it is. It accesses a `javascript` property of the `document` object, which in most cases will be `undefined` but in this case is the OP's form element with `name='javascript'`.

Comment: @nnnnnn but it seems OP likes to give tricky names to elements

Comment: What is tricky about the name of the elements? How should I do it differently?

Comment: Note that `= ( document.javascript.alu1.value - 0 );` is a needlessly long way to convert a string to a number. The parentheses are redundant, and you can just use the unary plus operator, a little something like this: `= +document.javascript.alu1.value;`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var getal7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('totaal1').textContent) +
  parseFloat(document.getElementById('totaal2').textContent);
```

Comment: if `totaal1` and `totaal2` are guaranteed to be integer value then you can wrap them like `+(document.....totaal1) + +(document....totaal2)`

Comment: My bad. Should be fixed.

Comment: var getal7 doens't work, it adds up the numbers wrong, even if they are whole number 5 + 5 = 11.

But this does seem to work: [edit: no it doesn't work aswell, 5.6 +6.2 = 10, so this one doesn't work aswell]
`document.getElementById('totaal3').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('totaal1').innerHTML) + parseInt(document.getElementById('totaal2').innerHTML);`

Comment: Use `parseFloat` and `innerContent` instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work sadly. I think there is something fundamentally wrong with this code.